# Why different smartphones with same Megapixel camera have different quality of image?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I am image processing student. Nowdays there are different brands of smartphones available. But the common thing is two different big brand smartphones with same Megapixel camera have different quality of image.

Moreover,the Digital cameras with same megapixel resolution have altogether best quality. Why is it so?

Comment: @ThP - that's pretty much the answer. [This link](http://www.cnet.com/news/camera-megapixels-why-more-isnt-always-better-smartphones-unlocked/) does a nice summary of why as well.

Comment: @Batman: posted as an answer. Very good summary in the link.

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure this is the right place to ask (Perhaps photo.stackexchange.com?) but this is my view on the subject. The term 'Megapixel' has little if any to do with image quality nowadays, since all the popular devices have sufficient amount of pixels. Way more important is the image processing algorithms, optics and sensor size. All digital cameras have huge advantage on the last two while smartphones usually 'make up' for this with image processing algorithms, but not enough to achieve similar quality.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the sensor will see the picture trough a lens : the resolution of the lense as a power spread function ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_spread_function )
Then there is some filters to avoid aliasing with the sensor matrix (low pass filter that limits the PSF.
The noise on the sensor can limit the effective resolution
The digital post processing can affect perception of the final picture